# solr single qoutes

Tags: solr, filter

I am new to solr, and I have one issue. My orginal string is "crohn's", and when I type something like "crohn's" it returns fine, and also when I type something like "crohn" it's also returns fine, but when I type "crohns" it does not return the string "crohn's"

Here is my schma.xml code

```
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider use `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` to strip the possessive "'s" from each subword.

Example:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1"/>
</analyzer>
```

The `stemEnglishPossessive` property does the trick. Actually its default value is 1.